# Android Custom Keyboard Layout as a Vector Asset

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I am attempting to create a custom keyboard where a vector image is the keyboard itself. Rather than having a custom xml file in the directory res/xml and defining a Keyboard tag, I want to have solely the image as the keyboard. I wanted to know if this is even possible to do because all of the examples I have seen thus far regarding how to create a custom keyboard is just defining an xml file for the layout of the keys and placing it inside of a KeyboardView. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. To create a cusotm keyboard you need [KeyboardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) and [Keyboard](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html) classes.

Also, I don't understand why would you need it. Do you want a background/theme for your keyboard? If yes, you can do it like this : `mKeyboardView.setBackground(drawable/color)` Also, there are other ways to set theme(including key border/background/color etc) for a keyboard, but since you are only concern to learn if it's possible to create a custom keyboard via vector asset. So, the answer is no.